# "find" doesn't list all files under specific directories

Tags: directory, find, recursive

I'm attempting to get a list of all files under specific folders, recursively, with the "find" command.

```
find /  -path "/usr/sbin/*" -o -path "/usr/bin/*" -o -path "/usr/local/sbin/*"-o -path "/usr/local/bin/*" -o -path "/sbin/*" -o -path "/bin/*" -o -path "*/etc/*"
```

The previous command, doesn't list the contents of /sbin and /bin , even though they do have content.

Any ideas of how to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sbin` is a symlink to `/usr/sbin` and `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.

`ls -ld /bin /sbin` will show you this.